# jquery to add scroll down pagination to show results

Tags: jquery, django, django-pagination

Currently I am using django-pagination to show limited results at one page

```
...
{% autopaginate object_list 10 %}
{% for item in object_list %}
...
{{ item }}
...
{% endfor %}
...
{% paginate %}
...
```

I need jquery to do this. load results at scroll down the page
e.g. https://www.google.com.pk/search?hl=en&q=nature+wallpapers&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1304&bih=680&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=fFQJUILdN4bBtAbNhJGoCQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [django-endless-pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). It is another django app for pagination. It has [pagination-on-scroll](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html#pagination-on-scroll).

Answer (score 0):

So you're asking how one would implement Infinite scroll in Django using jquery.

There's a lot of information out there on this subject, did you try google ?

http://palewi.re/posts/2010/11/07/django-recipe-twitter-style-infinite-scroll/